# How to connect three wires in electronics (extra low voltage) without PCB or soldering

Tags: wiring, split

I need to share 24 V (max 2 A) coming into my electronics enclosure between two consumers (a fan and an electronic module). The external connector is D-sub, internally I use crimped contacts, so no soldering. How can I "split" the 24 V and 0 V wires into two pairs?

At home, for 230 V, I use Wago 221. I see they are specified from wire size of 0.2 mm². So I could probably use them if I use 0.2+ mm² wires in my enclosure, but it feels like overkill. In the end, they can take 4 mm² wires and 300 V @ 20 A. Is there anything smaller? Or is it common to use Wago in extra low voltage devices?

Soldering is discouraged at my work due to reliability requirements.

Comment: No, Wago connectors (and other similar types) aren't commonly used inside low voltage equipment, they're really aimed at maintenance-free mains wiring where they can be used for inaccessible junctions above ceilings and under floors. But they're also starting to get used for switches and sockets where they can be installed quicker than screw terminals.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to connect wires without soldering:

- Crimp connectors (IDC) (aka "telecom butt splice," "quick splice," etc.)
- Wire nuts
- Lever nuts (Wago)
- Terminal/distribution blocks

Do your connections need to be easily disconnected? If so, you may want to avoid crimp connectors and probably wire nuts as well.

As you observed, the lever nuts have a minimum wire gauge to ensure a reliable connection. You can use lever nuts for low voltage applications, but you may need to use unnecessarily larger (and thus more expensive) wire.